# Solving LMS system with trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, least-squares

I have a bunch of points $[x_n, y_n, z_n]$ and I want to find the angles $\vartheta_s$, $\vartheta_t$ and $\vartheta_y$ that minimize

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
 &\sum_{n=0}^{N}  (\, (\cos{\vartheta_y}\left[ x_n\cos{\vartheta_s}-y_n\sin{\vartheta_s} \right]\\
  &-\sin{\vartheta_y}\left[  \cos{\vartheta_t} \left(x_n\sin{\vartheta_s}+y_n\cos{\vartheta_s}\right) -z_n\sin{\vartheta_t}   \right])\cdot k_1\\
  & + 
 (\,\sin{\vartheta_y}\left[ x_n\cos{\vartheta_s}-y_n\sin{\vartheta_s} \right]\\
  &+\cos{\vartheta_y}\left[  \cos{\vartheta_t} \left(x_n\sin{\vartheta_s}+y_n\cos{\vartheta_s}\right) -z_n\sin{\vartheta_t}   \right]\,)\cdot k_2\, )^2
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are known scalars.

Now, my first idea was to differentiate with respect to the three angles, which would give me three equations that I can set equal to zero. If I then group the terms to separate my three angles, I can get a matrix notation and invert it and solve for the three angles. However, after differentiating, I am not able to split my equations into three terms $\vartheta_t*...$, $\vartheta_y*...$, and $\vartheta_s*...$.

Are there any tricks to deal with trigonometric problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many solutions. You can minimize the sum by the following steps:

1. Calculate $\kappa$ from $k_1, k_2$ such that
   $$\cos{\kappa} = \frac{k_1}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}$$
   $$\sin{\kappa} = \frac{k_2}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}$$
2. Calculate the matrix $\mathbf{D}$ from the data $x_n, y_n, z_n$:
   $$
   \mathbf{D} = 
   \left[
   \begin{matrix}
   \sum{x_n x_n} & \sum{x_n y_n} & \sum{x_n z_n} \\
   \sum{x_n y_n} & \sum{y_n y_n} & \sum{y_n z_n} \\
   \sum{x_n z_n} & \sum{y_n z_n} & \sum{z_n z_n} 
   \end{matrix}
   \right]
   $$
3. Calculate (analytically (see [here](https://easychair.org/publications/preprint_open/fLnT) e.g.) or numerically) $\lambda_3$, the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{D}$, and the corresponding unit eigenvector $\mathbf{u_3}$ with components
   $$
   \mathbf{u_3}=
   \left[
   \begin{matrix}
   u_x \\
   u_y \\
   u_z
   \end{matrix}
   \right]
   $$
4. Choose any value for $\vartheta_s$.
5. Calculate $\vartheta_y-\kappa$ and $\vartheta_t$ from:
   $$
   \cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} = u_x \cos{\vartheta_s} - u_y \sin{\vartheta_s} \\
   u_z = \sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_t}
   $$

A more detailed explanation follows.

---

Write the sum of the squares $Z$ as

$$Z=\sum_{n=0}^{N} {t_n^2}$$

where

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
t_n &= k_1 \cdot (\cos{\vartheta_y}\left[ x_n\cos{\vartheta_s}-y_n\sin{\vartheta_s} \right] -\sin{\vartheta_y}\left[  \cos{\vartheta_t} \left(x_n\sin{\vartheta_s}+y_n\cos{\vartheta_s}\right) -z_n\sin{\vartheta_t}   \right])\\
   &+ 
 k_2 \cdot (\sin{\vartheta_y}\left[ x_n\cos{\vartheta_s}-y_n\sin{\vartheta_s} \right] +\cos{\vartheta_y}\left[  \cos{\vartheta_t} \left(x_n\sin{\vartheta_s}+y_n\cos{\vartheta_s}\right) -z_n\sin{\vartheta_t}   \right])
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Rearrange to get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
t_n &= (k_1 \cdot \cos{\vartheta_y} + k_2 \cdot \sin{\vartheta_y})
\left[ x_n\cos{\vartheta_s}-y_n\sin{\vartheta_s} \right] \\
&-(k_1 \cdot \sin{\vartheta_y} - k_2 \cdot \cos{\vartheta_y})\left[  \cos{\vartheta_t} \left(x_n\sin{\vartheta_s}+y_n\cos{\vartheta_s}\right) -z_n\sin{\vartheta_t}   \right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Now define $\kappa$ such that
$$\cos{\kappa} = \frac{k_1}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}$$
$$\sin{\kappa} = \frac{k_2}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}$$

Then
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{t_n}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}} 
&= (\cos{\kappa} \cdot \cos{\vartheta_y} + \sin{\kappa} \cdot \sin{\vartheta_y})
\left[ x_n\cos{\vartheta_s}-y_n\sin{\vartheta_s} \right] \\
&-(\cos{\kappa} \cdot \sin{\vartheta_y} - \sin{\kappa} \cdot \cos{\vartheta_y})\left[  \cos{\vartheta_t} \left(x_n\sin{\vartheta_s}+y_n\cos{\vartheta_s}\right) -z_n\sin{\vartheta_t}   \right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Or
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{t_n}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}} 
&= \cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)}
\left[ x_n\cos{\vartheta_s}-y_n\sin{\vartheta_s} \right] \\
&-\sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)}\left[  \cos{\vartheta_t} \left(x_n\sin{\vartheta_s}+y_n\cos{\vartheta_s}\right) -z_n\sin{\vartheta_t}   \right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

So the impact of the scalars $k_1$ and $k_2$ can be confined to an additive offset of $\vartheta_y$.

Rearrange again to this form
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{t_n}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}} 
&= x_n \left[\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \cos{\vartheta_s}-\sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_s} \cos{\vartheta_t} \right]\\
&+ y_n \left[-\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_s} - \sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \cos{\vartheta_s} \cos{\vartheta_t} \right]\\
&+ z_n \left[\sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_t} \right]
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Then write a column column vector of the $t_n$'s

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}} \mathbf{t}
&=\left[
\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{x}&\mathbf{y}&\mathbf{z}
\end{matrix}
\right]
\mathbf{\Phi} \\
&=\mathbf{X} \mathbf{\Phi}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

where $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ are column vectors of $x_n$,  $y_n$ and $z_n$, respectively, and 
$$
\mathbf{\Phi}=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \cos{\vartheta_s}-\sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_s} \cos{\vartheta_t} \\
-\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_s} - \sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \cos{\vartheta_s} \cos{\vartheta_t} \\
\sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_t}
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Then
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
Z 
&= \mathbf{t^T} \mathbf{t} \\
&= (k_1^2 + k_2^2) \mathbf{\Phi^T} \mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{\Phi} \\
&= (k_1^2 + k_2^2) \mathbf{\Phi^T} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{\Phi} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

where
$$
\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{X^T} \mathbf{X} = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\sum{x_n x_n} & \sum{x_n y_n} & \sum{x_n z_n} \\
\sum{x_n y_n} & \sum{y_n y_n} & \sum{y_n z_n} \\
\sum{x_n z_n} & \sum{y_n z_n} & \sum{z_n z_n} 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

It can be shown that $\mathbf{\Phi^T \Phi} \equiv 1$ so $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is a unit vector. Further, $\mathbf{D}$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix with positive eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \lambda_3$ and corresponding unit eigenvectors $\mathbf{u_1}$, $\mathbf{u_2}$ and $\mathbf{u_3}$ that are mutually orthogonal. From this we observe that $Z$ is minimized by setting $\mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{u_3}$, the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue:

$$
\mathbf{\Phi}=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \cos{\vartheta_s}-\sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_s} \cos{\vartheta_t} \\
-\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_s} - \sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \cos{\vartheta_s} \cos{\vartheta_t} \\
\sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_t}
\end{matrix}
\right]=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
u_x \\
u_y \\
u_z
\end{matrix}
\right]=\mathbf{u_3}
$$

This system of three simultaneous equations can be solved by multiplying the first by $\cos{\vartheta_s}$ and the second by $\sin{\vartheta_s}$ and subtracting to give

$$
\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} = u_x \cos{\vartheta_s} - u_y \sin{\vartheta_s}
$$

There are infinitely many solutions. Choose any value for $\vartheta_s$. Then calculate $\cos{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)}$ by the previous equation. Finally calculate $\vartheta_t$ from $u_z = \sin{(\vartheta_y-\kappa)} \sin{\vartheta_t}$.

The minimal value for $Z$ is $Z_{min}=\lambda_3 (z_1^2 + z_2^2)$.